# Is there a way to prevent a partition on a usb key from being mounted?

Tags: usb, partitioning, mount, automount

Is there a way to block certain partitions on a usb key from being mounted? Not at the OS level, but at the usb key level. I'd like to be able to put my key in any other computer (windows, osx, linux) and have it not automount one of the partitions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt the partition using [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/truecrypt-portable#Y562), and put the truecrypt executables in one of the other partitions so you can run them, and mount the encrypted partition.

Comment: That's what I was planning to do with at least of the partitions. But I have another partition which contains an OS that I would like to not have mounted when plugged into another computer.